# Generate a new PDF using a PDF file result in white places

Tags: android, pdf-generation

I fails to give an appropriate title to the questions. :)

Any how I need to split (get) a page from a existing PDF file. I am using droidtext for this.

My code is

```
  try {

        String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/test123.pdf";
                    /*Read Existing PDF*/ 
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.open();

        File outfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/test_new.pdf");
        if (!outfile.exists())
            outfile.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);

        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, decfos);
        document.open();
        /*Getting First page*/  
        PdfImportedPage page = writer.getImportedPage(reader, 1);

        Image instance = Image.getInstance(page);

        document.add(instance);
        document.close();

    } catch (DocumentException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I want to create a one page pdf from "test123.pdf" file. It is creating new PDF.

But the problem is in new PDF file there are white borders. How can I remove these white spaces.
In original PDF there is no such white borders.

[image]

**EDIT**
  I give another try with follwing code. But it gives null pointer exception at `copy.addPage(page);`

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/test123.pdf";
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(path);

        PdfImportedPage page;
        PdfSmartCopy.PageStamp stamp;
        File outfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + "/test_new.pdf");
        Document doc = new Document();
        if (!outfile.exists())
            outfile.createNewFile();

        FileOutputStream decfos = new FileOutputStream(outfile);
        PdfSmartCopy copy = new PdfSmartCopy(doc, decfos);
        page = copy.getImportedPage(reader, 5);

        stamp = copy.createPageStamp(page);

        stamp.alterContents();
        copy.addPage(page);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I voted the question down because of two reasons:

1. You didn't read the official documentation. See [Edit DirectContent of iTextSharp PdfSmartCopy class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740390/edit-directcontent-of-itextsharp-pdfsmartcopy-class/12741148#12741148) to find out why not reading the documentation is wrong.
2. I'm the original developer of iText, and I DO NOT ENDORSE the use of DroidText. It's not an official iText release. I strongly discourage its use: http://lowagie.com/itext2 Note that I live in Belgium, and by Belgian law, I have the moral rights on all the copyright I produced. This includes iText 2.1.7.

As for your question: you're creating pages with format A4. To these pages you add imported pages with an unknown size. If those pages are of size A4 too, they will fit. If they have a different size, they won't. Either they'll be clipped, or they'll have unnecessary margins.

Comment: about  **1** `I am looking in droidtext code to find the answer. I will read the chapter, you mentioned and try the solution `. **2** `I will keep in mind this.`

Comment: You have two better options to split PDFs: using PdfCopy (in combination with PdfReader.selectPages() or selecting the pages yourself) and using PdfStamper and PdfReader.selectPages(). The former is better if you need different PDFs as a result of the split action; I prefer the latter if I need only one PDF: a selection of pages of the original document.

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I will defiantly move to `iText`. I told my client to buy the license. But for now I need to do with droidtext to show something. I really fell myself dumb at the moment. Can you please help me with some code? I try with other code but failed to do so. See my edits in question.

Comment: Why are you creating a PageStamp? You aren't doing anything with it. Maybe that's the problem.